# M2 - Cannot change deploy mode to Production

Tags: magento2, deploy, command-line, production-mode

I am trying to set the deploy mode on an M2 instance to Production from Developer.
On my local environment however I keep getting the error message:

```
Command returned non-zero exit code:
'/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JWM2/bin/magento setup:di:compile'
```

When it errors and escapes back to the prompt, I type `echo $?` and simply get `1` returned back.

On the recommendation of another post, I have tried increasing the php memory_limit which didn't help. I have also tried running the `setup:di:compile` command separately, but this completed successfully, however there were some errors relating to the dependancies already existing in context objects for a couple of modules.

When I try to change the deploy mode on the production server, the issue lies with the `setup:static-content:deploy` part of the process with the issue being with the Magento Backend theme.

If I add the flag `--skip-compilation` to the `deploy:mode:set production` then it slides in to the correct mode without problem.

Has anyone got any ideas how I can make this work with compilation?

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin/php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/JWM2/bin/magento -vvv setup:di:compile
```

it will show you what problem do you have

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't tell me anything new, I'm not sure if -vvv is used in all of the bin/.magento scripts.